# Работа с компонентами Delphi

Tags: delphi

Можете подсказать, как работают компоненты в Delphi. Допустим мне нужно загрузить какую-то информацию из файла в TMemo. Как сделать так, чтобы это происходило прямо при запуске программы, а не по нажатию кнопки(той же кнопки "загрузить", к примеру)

Comment: добавить эту загрузку в OnCreate формы?

Comment: @KoVadim То есть, так как такого события отдельно для компонентов, например того же Memo нет, то нужно чтение из файла кидать на форму и там уже прописывать, например, добавить строку в Memo с информацией из файла?

Comment: я сейчас пересмотрел события, которые есть у TMemo и я там не вижу ничего такого. Но я не вижу ничего зазорного добавить это в OnCreate формы.

Comment: @KoVadim Ну это понятно, но я же точно смогу работать с компонентами(например, загружать в них данные с файла) через события главной формы ? Просто только начинаю использовать GUI, поэтому такие вопросы :)

Comment: В большинстве случаев - да. Но серебряной пули нет

Comment: компоненты в большинстве своем размещаются на форме (становятся членами класса формы) и ей управляются, в т.ч. форма (owner) контролирует время жизни компонентов. Все события компонентов, которые вы будете обрабатывать будут описаны также в классе формы (созданные в инспекторах IDE). В связи с этим, oncreate формы ничем в данном случае не будет отличаться от любого другого  события. Это в целом стандартный подход к инициализации.

Comment: Но если ваш файл достаточно объемный, то это может затормозить запуск формы, что будет выглядеть нежелательным,в таком случаев можно чтение файла вынести в отдельный поток, и потом уже синхронизовать с основным.